# Logics for multi-agent and distributed systems and algorithms

Tags: distributed-systems, concurrency, temporal-logic

The various temporal logics are particularly suitable for the specification and verification of concurrent computer programs. Are there logics that are particularly suitable for the specification and verification of multi-agent and distributed systems and algorithms? Or are the temporal logics used as-is for these purposes as well?

Answer (score 1):

TLA+ is commonly used for verification of distributed algorithms. I've seen it actively used by researchers and industry engineers/architects.